# RStudio Debugger - Is it possible to run "next 'n' steps" in debugging mode?

Tags: r, debugging, rstudio

Something like line-by-line debugging but instead of going 1 step at a time ask the debugger to run the next "n" steps before it goes interactive in the console again.

Comment: Why don't you set the `browser()` command where you need it (Then you can use `Continue` to reach the next line of interest)? Alternativly, you can use breakpoints.

Comment: Thanks! I got the desired functionality by doing it with breakpoints. @Christoph